Is there a way to use bcc with django mailgun mime
I am using Mailgun mime with my django project to send out newsletters but i'm not sure if their is a way to use blind carbon copy so that every recipient can't view every other recipients email addresses
i have looked from through the documentation for mailgun and the mailgun mime module but it doesn't seem to be very clear if you can or not
